# Write a list of list into a file using list comprehension

Tags: python

suppose we have a list of list called `A`:

```
A = [[1, 100, 200, 300],[2, 300, 400, 500]]
```

and we want to write `A` into a file with format below:

```
"1\t\100\t\200\t300\n2\t\300\t400\t500"
```

it's all in `string`

can it be accomplished by using list comprehension on `write()` or `writelines()` function ?

Comment: It can, but you shouldn't use a comprehension for the side effects of the involved expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `f` is the file object you want to write to, you can do:

```
f.write('\n'.join('\t'.join(map(str, s)) for s in A))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a different solution:

```
A = [[1, 100, 200, 300], [2, 300, 400, 500]]

def wit(x):
    for i in range(x):
        retlis = str(A[i]).replace(",", "").replace("]", "").replace("[", "")
        open("list.txt", "a+").write(retlis + "\n\n")

wit(len(A))
```

**list.txt:**

```
1 100 200 300

2 300 400 500
```